# Name of fallacious reasoning about the reality of abstractions

Tags: fallacies, skepticism, debate, universals

There is a kind of reasoning that is often heard, where the irreality of some abstraction is inferred from the fact that entities that fall under it are not perfectly homogenous.

(1) A lot of times one will hear this at the beginning of talks about some academic subject.
E.g.:
"I am invited to talk about Penguins. But there really is no such thing as Penguins. There are Aptenodytes, Eudyptula, etc. ..."

(2) At other times one will hear such argument in political debate, often where the abstraction in question denotes a group whose political agency is disputed.
E.g.:
"There is no such thing as Islam, there are sunni, shia, ...",
"There is no such thing as the French, there are alsacians, brittanians, ..."

(3) Sometimes in more philosophical contexts one might even hear something along the lines of:
"Every stone is different, therefore there is no such thing as 'stones'."
This form seems to be taking (1) and (2) to their logical conclusion.

While the conclusion of these arguments might be a perfectly valid position regarding the problem of universals, the argument itself seems blatantly fallacious. The concepts of Penguins, Islam, French, stones are partial abstractions and do not imply perfect homogeneity, nor does the fact that they have identifiable subclasses characterized by relevant properties imply that their general abstraction is useless, meaningless, or "fictional", as is sometimes claimed.

i have seen this kind of argument so much that i wonder if there is an established name for it, or if there is some historic philosophical debate in which it featured prominently.

Comment: Maybe [Reification fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy)).

Comment: That's not quite it i think. The wikipedia page describes different ways in which it has been criticized to in some sense ascribe reality to abstract concepts, but the type of argument i have described is not among them. note that the argument i describe can be and is applied to any names whatsoever, except for proper names. even then it might be applied based on temporal heterogeneity. the term concluded to be "fictitious" does not have to be a hypothetical construct or such.

Comment: You might like to read some Buddhist writings on composite phenomena and impermanence. The mistaken reification of composite phenomena, abstractions or conceptual imputations would be called ignorance.    . .

Comment: Your examples are not of reasoning, fallacious or otherwise. They are of a rhetorical turn of phrase used for shock value to call attention to a phenomenon routinely overlooked. The name is [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole), exaggeration not meant to be taken literally. The "really" in "there really is no such thing" indicates that the "thing" will be used not in the usual sense, but in a special overprecise one. In which case, what is said is correct, and it intends no conclusion about (non) existence of universals as such.

Comment: @Conifold this might be true for many cases of (1)(hence my inclusion of 'really' only here), but at least for the other two forms i have certainly encountered cases where people unmistakably intended to deny the reality of the concept in question. this is made abundantly clear when that concept is called a "fantasy", a "delusion", "fictitious" etc., when its use is condemned even, or judged as "erroneous",  which i have all witnessed

Comment: Even then it is certainly not an argument for/against the existence of universals. It is a statement of opinion concerning a specific concept. One may believe that what a concept covers is so heterogenous that it becomes useless or worse, misleading. Whether it is or not is subject to judgment, not argument, which can be good or bad, but not fallacious. It can be reasoned about by comparing to other concepts, citing examples, etc., and the case made can be judged plausible or not. But it is not made in what you are quoting, and hence that is not an argument, even in a loose sense.

Comment: the argument i have described (some x are different) (a) is indeed an argument -- a series of statements intended to determine the degree of truth of another statement -- namely that the concept of "x" is irreal, or "fictitious", etc. (b) exists in real life in the sense that people invoke it in support of the aforementioned consequent (c) is indeed fallacious. which of these do you disagree with?

Comment: All of them. It is not an argument ("some x a different" is just a reference to heterogeneity), whether the concept "exists" is subject to opinion, and a non-argument can not be a fallacy. A series of statements intended to determine the degree of truth of another statement need not be an argument generally, it can be a list of inputs for a judgment call, for example.

Comment: that something is subject to opinion certainly does not imply that it cannot be argued for. moreover, assuming the dictionary definition of 'argument', whether or not something is an argument depends only on whether it is in fact used in support of another statement. so if i can give you one real life example (like a blog post or newspaper article) then this should settle the matter, correct?

Comment: I agree that opinions are argued for, but whether the argumehnt is successful does not always depend on its validity alone. It also depends on the judgment standards. "Every x is different" is what is called a value-laden claim, and having "wrong" evaluation standards is not a mistake in reasoning (fallacy). Are x-s different enough be subsumed under a genuine concept? I can see how one may answer no for "stone" or "religion". It does not mean denying that people use and understand those words, it means judging that the lumping involved leads to something "misguided" or "fictitious".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94629/discussion-between-user3636325-and-conifold).

Comment: "A lot of times one will hear this at the beginning of talks about some academic subject". Wow, not in my experience. I can't imagine a real zoologist, e.g., denying, even as a rhetorical device, that there is such a thing as penguins (unless, maybe, in the case in which "penguin" is so over- and mis-applied by laymen that it truly *is* a poor category--but in that case, this wouldn't be an improper thing to point out).

Comment: maybe penguin was a bad example. i know nothing of penguins.

Comment: My point was not about penguins (that's why I used "e.g."), but about how real scientists speak about their areas of expertise. I also can't imagine a meteorologist saying there are no clouds, a neuroscientist saying there are no neurons, a chemist saying there are no atoms, an astrophysicist saying there are no stars, etc

Comment: @Chelonian two examples from a quick google search: https://imgur.com/a/h3XpgPU

Comment: Nice work, but I'm not sure whether these are errors or not. Maybe to a taxonomist "mammal" *is*, arguably at least, an unhelpful/misleading (laymen's?) category label? For further discussion, we would take it to chat.